# Pandas: Create a data frame based on rows of another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, character

I have a problem, a somewhat complicated one.

I have a data frame like this:

```
   commodity_name first_delivery_date last_delivery_date  last_trading_date   tenor   delivery_window new_tenor    Vol
   <chr>          <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>   <chr>           <chr>      <int>
  1 oil            2021-06-01 00:00:00 2021-06-30 00:00:00 2021-04-30 00:00:00 month   Jun 21          Jun 21     29000
  2 gold           2022-03-01 00:00:00 2022-03-31 00:00:00 2022-02-28 00:00:00 month   Mar 22          Mar 22      -800
  3 oil            2021-07-01 00:00:00 2021-07-31 00:00:00 2021-05-31 00:00:00 month   Jul 21          Jul 21    -21000
  4 gold           2021-09-01 00:00:00 2021-09-30 00:00:00 2021-08-31 00:00:00 month   Sep 21          Sep 21      1100
  5 gold           2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-02-28 00:00:00 2021-01-29 00:00:00 month   Feb 21          Feb 21     -3000
  6 depower        2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-01-31 00:00:00 2020-12-30 00:00:00 quarter Jan 21          Q1 21         -3
  7 oil            2022-04-01 00:00:00 2022-04-30 00:00:00 2022-02-28 00:00:00 month   Apr 22          Apr 22     23000
  8 czpower        2023-02-01 00:00:00 2023-02-28 00:00:00 2023-01-30 00:00:00 quarter Feb 23          Q1 23         26
  9 oil            2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-02-28 00:00:00 2020-12-31 00:00:00 quarter Feb 21          Q1 21     -17000
 10 gold           2021-05-01 00:00:00 2021-05-31 00:00:00 2021-04-30 00:00:00 month   May 21          May 21      2400
```

And from it I would like to create another data frame, based on the following conditions:

- For Year `YY`, If the `new_tenor` is `Q1 YY` in the old data frame: create three rows in the new data frame where the `new_tenor` is `Jan YY`, `Feb YY` and `Mar YY`, respectively. All other variables remain the same;
- If the `new_tenor` is `Q2 YY` in the old data frame: create three rows in the new data frame where the `new_tenor` is `Apr YY`, `May YY` and `Jun YY`, respectively. All other variables remain the same;
- If the `new_tenor` is `Q3 YY` in the old data frame: create three rows in the new data frame where the `new_tenor` is `Jul YY`, `Aug YY` and `Sep YY`, respectively. All other variables remain the same;
- If the `new_tenor` is `Q4 YY` in the old data frame: create three rows in the new data frame where the `new_tenor` is `Oct YY`, `Nov YY` and `Dec YY`, respectively. All other variables remain the same;
- If the `new_tenor` is `Cal YY` in the old data frame: create six rows in the new data frame where the `new_tenor` is `Jan YY+1`, `Feb YY+1`, `Mar YY+1`, `Q2 YY+1`, `Q3 YY+1` and `Q4 YY+1`, respectively. All other variables remain the same;

The problem is straightforward and depends mainly on the value of `YY`, everything else remains the same in the new data frame as in the old one.

I tried solving the problem using the following code:

```
my_df = []


for index, row in ss.iterrows():
    
# d = row["NewTenor"].split()

# year = d[1]
        
print(year)

if "Cal" in row["NewTenor"]:
    
    # Go to next year
    
    # Add Jan, Feb, and Mar
    
    temp_1 = row
    
    temp_1['NewTenor'] = temp_1['NewTenor'].replace({'Cal':'Jan','21':'22','22':'23','23':'24'})
    
    temp_2 = row
    
    temp_2['NewTenor'] = temp_2['NewTenor'].replace({'Cal':'Feb','21':'22','22':'23','23':'24'})
    
    temp_3 = row
    
    temp_3['NewTenor'] = temp_3['NewTenor'].replace({'Cal':'Mar','21':'22','22':'23','23':'24'})
    
    # Add Q2, Q3, and Q4
    
    temp_4 = row
    
    temp_4['NewTenor'] = temp_1['NewTenor'].replace({'Cal':'Q2','21':'22','22':'23','23':'24'})
    
    temp_5 = row
    
    temp_5['NewTenor'] = temp_1['NewTenor'].replace({'Cal':'Q3','21':'22','22':'23','23':'24'})
    
    temp_6 = row
    
    temp_6['NewTenor'] = temp_1['NewTenor'].replace({'Cal':'Q4','21':'22','22':'23','23':'24'})
    
    # Append to data frame
    
    my_df.append(temp_1)
    my_df.append(temp_2)
    my_df.append(temp_3)
    my_df.append(temp_4)
    my_df.append(temp_5)
    my_df.append(temp_6)
    
elif "Q1" in row["NewTenor"]:
    
    # Add Jan, Feb, and Mar
    
    temp_1 = row
    
    temp_1['NewTenor'] = temp_1['NewTenor'].replace({'Q1':'Jan'})
    
    temp_2 = row
    
    temp_2['NewTenor'] = temp_2['NewTenor'].replace({'Q1':'Feb'})
    
    temp_3 = row
    
    temp_3['NewTenor'] = temp_3['NewTenor'].replace({'Q1':'Mar'})
    
    # Append to data frame
    
    my_df.append(temp_1)
    my_df.append(temp_2)
    my_df.append(temp_3)
    
    
elif "Q2" in row["NewTenor"]:
    
    # Add Apr, May, and Jun
    
    temp_1 = row
    
    temp_1['NewTenor'] = temp_1['NewTenor'].replace({'Q2':'Apr'})
    
    temp_2 = row
    
    temp_2['NewTenor'] = temp_2['NewTenor'].replace({'Q2':'May'})
    
    temp_3 = row
    
    temp_3['NewTenor'] = temp_3['NewTenor'].replace({'Q2':'Jun'})
    
    
    # Append to data frame
    
    my_df.append(temp_1)
    my_df.append(temp_2)
    my_df.append(temp_3)
    
elif "Q3" in row["NewTenor"]:
    
    # Add Jul, Aug, and Sep
    
    temp_1 = row
    
    temp_1['NewTenor'] = temp_1['NewTenor'].replace({'Q3':'Jul'})
    
    temp_2 = row
    
    temp_2['NewTenor'] = temp_2['NewTenor'].replace({'Q3':'Aug'})
    
    temp_3 = row
    
    temp_3['NewTenor'] = temp_3['NewTenor'].replace({'Q3':'Sep'})
    
    # Append to data frame
    
    my_df.append(temp_1)
    my_df.append(temp_2)
    my_df.append(temp_3)
    
else :
    
    # Add Oct, Nov, and Dec
    
    temp_1 = row
    
    temp_1['NewTenor'] = temp_1['NewTenor'].replace({'Q4':'Oct'})
    
    temp_2 = row
    
    temp_2['NewTenor'] = temp_2['NewTenor'].replace({'Q4':'Nov'})
    
    temp_3 = row
    
    temp_3['NewTenor'] = temp_3['NewTenor'].replace({'Q4':'Dec'})
    
    # Append to data frame
    
    my_df.append(temp_1)
    my_df.append(temp_2)
    my_df.append(temp_3)
    
    
 my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_df)
```

Which is not sophisticated, and it always gives me errors.

Can someone please help me create the new data frame? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```py
def split_tenor(tenor):
    start, year = tenor.split(" ")
    if start == "Cal":
        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]
        year = int(year) + 1
    elif start == "Q1":
        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
    elif start == "Q2":
        months = ["Apr", "May", "Jun"]
    elif start == "Q3":
        months = ["Jul", "Aug", "Sep"]
    elif start == "Q4":
        months = ["Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    else:
        return tenor

    return [f"{m} {year}" for m in months]

df["new_tenor"] = df["new_tenor"].apply(split_tenor)
df.explode("new_tenor")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I tried on a subset of the data and it gives the expected results.